# Is it okay to add tons of Firebase ValueEventListener on Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I love using Firebase Realtime Database and I use it a lot. So in my apps there are literally tons of them using ValueEventListener of their own. So is it making my app slower or consume the simultaneous connection limit of Firebase? And if the listener automatically removed, on which phase that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single app instance only keeps a single connection open to the Firebase Database back-end, so it counts as 1 against your free quota of 100 simultaneous connections.

But keeping listeners for data you don't need synchronized is wasteful, so for anything but demos you should actively manage your connections.

Comment: so which best way to remove the unused listener? is it okay if i remove it in onDestroy of activity or onPause?

Comment: You should remove listeners when you don't need the up to date data anymore. Typically you'd do this in the inverse of where you attach them. So if you attach in `onCreate()`, you'd remove in `onDestroy()`. If you attach in `onStart()`, you remove in `onStop()`, etc.